# How to click a element if a tag is missing

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<a href="" class="ng-binding ng-scope outside-month">1</a>
<a href="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">1</a>
```

I want to do a click on the second element where the **outside-month** tag is missing. How can I achieve this?

Is there a special selenium function or do I have to write a special xpath expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **outside-month** is missing on target `element` you should use `=` with `class name` as below `xpath`:-

```
String xPath = "//a[@class = 'ng-binding ng-scope']";
```

or

if you want to use `contains` and target element is the last with containing `class name` you should pass `last()` as below :-

```
String xPath = "(//a[contains(@class, 'ng-binding ng-scope')])[last()]";
```

or

if you want to use `contains` and target element is not the last element with containing `class name` you should pass appropriate `index` as below :-

```
String xPath = "(//a[contains(@class, 'ng-binding ng-scope')])[2]";
```

or

if you want **outside-month** is missing but **ng-binding ng-scope** present you should try as below :-

```
String xPath = "//a[contains(@class, 'ng-binding ng-scope') and not(contains(@class, 'outside-month'))]";
```

Use anyone of the above `xPath` and perform `click` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));
el.click();
```

**Note** :- Be ensure before finding `element` that it is not inside any `frame`. If it is inside any `frame` you need to `switch` that `frame` first as :- `driver.switchTo().frame("frame name or id")`

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 2):

For your scenario I imagine you could devise an XPath expression that uses the `not()` and `contains()` operators together.

Something along the lines of:

```
//a[not(contains(@class, 'outside-month'))]
```

I haven't tested whether this works or not but let me know if not and I can help refine it.

Answer (score 0):

in that element outside-month it's not a tag or attribute it's just a bigger class name
so what you need is to find a tag that have ng-binding ng-scope class name:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']")).click();
```